# Build App with Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have an application built with MongoDB+NodeJS+AngularJS.

I'm researching about how to make the app reactive to changes the way Meteor and Firebase provide out-of-the-box.

If I use Firebase and AngularJS where should I put server-side logic?

For example, in my app I have a concept of project that can be share with other users, today when a project is shared the server has logic which checks if the email to share with is already a registered user, creates invite data if not and send email either way.

Where does that logic go?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the **M**, the **A** and the **N**, so I think you are looking for the [MEAN Stack](http://mean.io/)

[image]

Check out the documentation [here](http://learn.mean.io/).

Comment: Hi, I did check it, it look to large of a cannon for our needs, also does MEAN provide soft-real-time like Meteor and Firebase?